# How to get a particular value from a Url in iOS - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, swift3

I have a url that is reg code attached to it. I just want to retrieve the reg code 7954741093-41547468-3 from the below url

```
https://mycode.funny.net/mycode/Registrations/7954741093-41547468-3?api-version=2011-04
```

Comment: So what's the question here? What have you tried so far? Ever heard of regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
let regCode:String = (url.components(separatedBy: "/").last?.components(separatedBy: "?").first)!
```

Where url is

```
let url:String = "https://mycode.funny.net/mycode/Registrations/7954741093-41547468-3?api-version=2011-04"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think using `URLComponents` is a little more robust:

```
let url = "https://mycode.funny.net/mycode/Registrations/7954741093-41547468-3?api-version=2011-04"
let components = URLComponents(string: url)
components?.path.components(separatedBy: "/").last
```